# vb.net code conditional logic

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have the following piece of code which works fine and does what it is intended for. But my source data has a line added to the very bottom and it makes this thing break. When I go and delete that last line, this code works fine. I dont want manually modify the file everyday this script runs. Following is the code. Is there any way I can ignore the last line of my input and process the rest of it. I know its a simple conditional if-else, but I dont have any clue about .net and someone else helped me write this code. Thanks in advance.

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    Dim strRow As String
    Dim strColSeperator As String
    Dim rowValues As String()
    strRow = Row.Line.ToString()
    If strRow.Contains(",") Then
        strColSeperator = (",")
    ElseIf strRow.Contains(";") Then
        strColSeperator = ";"
    End If

    rowValues = Row.Line.Split(CChar(strColSeperator))
    Row.Code = rowValues.GetValue(0).ToString()
    Row.Description = rowValues.GetValue(1).ToString()
    Row.Blank = rowValues.GetValue(2).ToString()
    Row.Weight = rowValues.GetValue(3).ToString()
    Row.Scan = rowValues.GetValue(4).ToString()

End Sub
```

Sample input data: 643492,PV STRIP 1X1 UTILITY UP,,56,393454
Last line of the input file: "EndDb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    Dim strRow As String
    Dim strColSeperator As String
    Dim rowValues As String()
    strRow = Row.Line.ToString()
    If strRow.Contains(",") Then
        strColSeperator = (",")
    ElseIf strRow.Contains(";") Then
        strColSeperator = ";"
    End If

    rowValues = Row.Line.Split(CChar(strColSeperator))
    If (rowValues.Length > 1) Then
    Row.Code = rowValues.GetValue(0).ToString()
    Row.Description = rowValues.GetValue(1).ToString()
    Row.Blank = rowValues.GetValue(2).ToString()
    Row.Weight = rowValues.GetValue(3).ToString()
    Row.Scan = rowValues.GetValue(4).ToString()
    End If

End Sub
```